# Bash Recursive Method not Finishing Method Call Stack

Tags: bash, for-loop, recursion

I'm new to Bash, and as a project I'm trying to create a shell script that will create a tree of folders. For example, if I tell it to create a tree that is 3 folders deep and 4 wide, then it would create a level of folders labeled 0, 1, and 2; then inside each of those folders it would create folders 0, 1, and 2, and so on until it reached 4 levels deep. (This would create 4^3 folders.)

Here is the code for the method I created:

```
function createLevel () { #param1 = number of levels of folders, param2 = number of folders per level
    numLevels=$1
    numPerLevel=$2
    if [ $numLevels -eq 1 ];
    then
        for ((i=0; i < numPerLevel; i++));
        do
            mkdir $i
        done
    else
        for ((i=0; i < numPerLevel; i++));
        do
            mkdir $i
            cd $i
            createLevel $((numLevels - 1)) $numPerLevel
            cd ..
        done
    fi
}
```

It usually just creates one branch, so for example it will create a 0 folder within a 0 folder within a 0 folder, but it will not trace back out and make the other folders. I feel like it's not finishing the method call stack and instead of going back and finishing the method, it just quits after it calls itself. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Michael Jaros's answer should solve most of your problem. But, your logic is a little bit off and this would put you in an endless recursive loop. The `else` statement should make sure that the `$numLevels` is greater than 1. So your else statement would become: `elif [ $numLevels -gt 1 ];`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare your variables `local` if you call the function recursively:

```
 local i
 local numLevels=$1
 local numPerLevel=$2
 [...]
```

Otherwise they will be overwritten by the "inner" calls.

Comment: Thanks Michael Jaros. I actually had to make i, numLevels, and numPerLevel local, but that fixed it!